# Flag / Star buttons are visible but locked for removed messages

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, flags

When you hover a message that has been deleted, you can see the flag/star buttons but cannot click on them. The reply button is removed.

What is the use of such a button if you can't use it?

I propose the following:

- Remove the star button, it isn't useful to be able to star a removed message
- Fix the flag button, for when you've seen what's in the message and feel like it needs mod attention

Comment: If they locked once the message is removed, I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @Xarcell what's the use of a locked button? If you remove the reply button, you should remove the others as well, unless they are useful.

Comment: Like I said, I don't see a problem with that. Although, that's not to say it's can't be improved by removing them. You have this topic flagged as a "BUG", when it should just be a "Feature Request".

Comment: @Xarcell I disagree. For some reason, the reply button was removed. I think the same reason applies to the other buttons, so there has been made some mistake which makes that they are not removed. If there is a good reason to treat the buttons different, then this wouldn't be a bug. But from what I see now it sure looks like one.

Comment: Well, I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. Still upvoted though.

Comment: @Xarcell Thanks for that of course, and thanks for your feedback.